gstreamer keeping buffers in GLMemory for nvh264enc SINK
I am having issues understanding why the nvh264enc fails on taking GLMemory as a sink.
GST 1.24.3 custom compile ubuntu, nvidia A10G
by downloading via gldownload, it works as expected
GST_DEBUG=1,nvh264enc:5 gst-launch-1.0 --eos-on-shutdown -v \
videotestsrc ! \
glupload ! glcolorconvert ! "video/x-raw(memory:GLMemory), format=RGBA" ! \
glvideomixer name=mix sink_0::alpha=1 ! \
gldownload ! \
nvh264enc bitrate=1000 preset=4 zerolatency=true ! \
h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 ! \
udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=10000

however attempting to keep the buffers in glmemory I get an error
GST_DEBUG=1,nvh264enc:5 gst-launch-1.0 --eos-on-shutdown -v \
videotestsrc ! \
glupload ! glcolorconvert ! "video/x-raw(memory:GLMemory), format=RGBA" ! \
glvideomixer name=mix sink_0::alpha=1 ! \
glcolorconvert ! "video/x-raw(memory:GLMemory), format=NV12" ! \
nvh264enc bitrate=1000 preset=4 zerolatency=true ! \
h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 ! \
udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=10000


ERROR nvenc gstnvbaseenc.c:2141:_map_gl_input_buffer:
could not register 0th
memory/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstNvH264Enc:nvh264enc0.GstPad:src: caps
= video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)2, profile=(string)main,
width=(int)320, height=(int)240, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1,
framerate=(fraction)30/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive,
colorimetry=(string)bt601, chroma-site=(string)jpeg

Pad Templates:  SINK template: 'sink'  
...
video/x-raw(memory:GLMemory)
   format: { (string)NV12, ...

Is it an incorrect assumption that the input with GLMemeory should work?
could it be

colorimetry=(string)bt601, chroma-site=(string)jpeg

is wrong for nvh264enc?
